# nested routing isn't working with react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I've been trying to render out CollectionPage and match the url with my page but my nested Route that's calling CollectionPage doesn't work for some reason!

here's a snippet from my shop.component that is being called at app.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import CollectionOverview from '.././../components/collections-overview/collections-overview.component';
import CollectionPage from '../collection/collection.component';

const ShopPage = ({ match }) => (

    <div className='shop-page'>
        <Route exact path={`${match.path}`} component={CollectionOverview} />
        <Route path={`${match.path}/:collectionId`} component={CollectionPage} />
    </div>

);


export default ShopPage;
```

Comment: Show us your router setup code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was going on, in my app.js I accidentally set my path='/shop/' so I just had to remove that 2nd '/'

Answer (score 0):

When I did this course an issue I had was that in App.js I had set exact for the shop route. Maybe you have it too :D

Comment: exact is only set to homepage and checkout in app.js